# How to get properly on Monday from a timestamp?

Tags: php, date, timezone, timestamp, strtotime

I am working with php5.5.1.

```
//date_default_timezone_get = UTC
date('d/m/Y ... H:i:s', 1400444640); // = Sunday 18/05/2014 ... 20:24
```

How do I get the current Monday of that week?

```
date('d/m/Y ... H:i:s', (strtotime('Monday this week', 1400444640))); // 19/05/2014 ... 00:00
```

Why do not I get a date Monday 12? How I can get it correctly?

Comment: Why should you get 12? That would be previous week. The Monday in current week falls on 19.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be the twelfth then you need to ask for the monday of the previous week.

```
date('d/m/Y ... H:i:s', (strtotime('previous week monday', 1400444640)));
```